# This domain (lnipkl.csb.app) is not authorized to run this operation

Tags: firebase, codesandbox

I'm learning to code in reactjs from the codesandbox editor. I want to integrate authentication with firebase. I set up authentication with google and facebook but when I try to check in my application if everything is working I get the following message

```
Error
This domain (lnipkl.csb.app) is not authorized to run this operation. Add it to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.
```

I went to the hosting part and tried to add a custom domain: *lnipkl.csb.app* but it does not add it.

In the *build->authentication-> sign-method* section I don't see where do I have to add the domain as the error message indicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorized domains changed location. Now it's in authentication->settings Section

[image]